# Работа с mouseenter и mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть проблема. ВОт код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let src = '';
  $('.leave').mouseover(function(){
    src = $(this).children('img').attr('src').slice(0,-4) + '_red.svg';
    $(this).children('img').attr('src',src);
  });

  $('.leave').mouseout(function(){
    src = $(this).children('img').attr('src').slice(0,-8) + '.svg';
    $(this).children('img').attr('src',src);
  });
 });
```

Суть в чем, мне необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на элемент у него сохранялся src как при наведении, и наведение не срабатывало на этом элементе. А у меня получается так, что когда я удаляю класс `leave`, то события все равно срабатываю на элементе.

Comment: обработчик добавляется конкретному элементу. После добавления, неважно присутствует класс или нет.

Comment: А я могу убрать с данного элемента обработчик? или как-то заблокировать. У меня была идея сделать layout прозрачный, но это немного дико.

Comment: _А я могу убрать с данного элемента обработчик?_ - да, в jquery, например есть метод [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативой использования `.mouseover()`, `.mouseout()` и отключения обработчиков при помощи `.off`, есть использование [метода](http://api.jquery.com/on/) `.on()`.

Который позволяет при написании скрипта не следить за наличием класса у элемента.

**Пример кода**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function onMouseover(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).css('background', '#000');
  }

  function onMouseout(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).css('background', '#fff');
  }

  $(document).on("mouseover", ".leave", onMouseover);
  $(document).on("mouseout", ".leave", onMouseout);
  
  $('.remove-class').click(function() {
    $('.leave').removeClass('leave');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box leave"></div>
  <div class="box leave"></div>
  <div class="box leave"></div>
</div>
<button class="remove-class">Удалить класс</button>
```

Comment: Наличие класса - это понятно. Я понял как сделать bind и unbind. Я при помощи этого смог сделать данную функцию. Спасибо.